# How can I call a c++ function using python

Tags: python, c++, windows, dll, ctypes

I want to know if there's a way to use a c++ function inside a python code

For example, after doing my research I did find this solution using .dll file.
But It can't find the function 
My code:

fun.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
extern int add(int a, int b) {
return a+b;
}
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World! from C++" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

compiling it using cmd:

> g++ fun.cpp -o fun.dll

Calling the function using Python, ctypes:

```
from ctypes import *
import os
mydll = cdll.LoadLibrary("C:/Users/User/Desktop/ctypes/fun.dll")

result= mydll.add(10,1)
print("Addition value:-"+result)
```

But I had this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "c:\Users\User.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.10.41019\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py",
>   line 43, in 
>       main(ptvsdArgs)   File "c:\Users\User.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.10.41019\pythonFiles\lib\python\old_ptvsd\ptvsd__main__.py",
>   line 432, in main
>       run()   File "c:\Users\User.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.10.41019\pythonFiles\lib\python\old_ptvsd\ptvsd__main__.py",
>   line 316, in run_file
>       runpy.run_path(target, run_name='**main**')   File "C:\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
>       pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)   File "C:\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
>       mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)   File "C:\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
>       exec(code, run_globals)   File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\ctypes\test.py", line 5, in 
>       result= mydll.add(10,1)   File "C:\Python36\lib\ctypes__init__.py", line 361, in **getattr**
>       func = self.**getitem**(name)   File "C:\Python36\lib\ctypes__init__.py", line 366, in **getitem**
>       func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self)) AttributeError: function 'add' not found

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145270/calling-c-c-from-python

Comment: this is likely a name mangling issue, try making `add` use C calling convention as in the first comment

Comment: In other words: The functions you want to call should be made `extern "C"`.

Comment: @MaxLanghof  I already did it but nothing changed

Comment: Well with the code you show it can't possibly work (unless you give ctypes the mangled name).

Comment: @MaxLanghof for example?

Comment: @ITWorld you need to use `extern "C"` not just `extern`, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/1041866/1358308 for example.  this was the first hit from google!

Comment: @SamMason I already did it, if you see my code, you'll see it

Comment: it's not in the code you posted, hence my comment!  you only have `extern`, check the many linked questions for the correct syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ mangles exported names.  Here's an example that should compile on Windows and Linux.  `__declspec(dllexport)` is required to export a function on Windows, but not Linux.  `extern "C"` is required to export the function name using C conventions, instead of the name-mangled C++ conventions.  The name-mangling is required in C++ to indicate the function parameters and return type, since C++ can have multiple functions with the same name but take different parameters.  The C convention does not support multiple functions with the same name.

fun.cpp:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#   define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define API
#endif

extern "C" API int add(int a, int b) {
    return a+b;
}
```

Python:

```
from ctypes import *

dll = CDLL('fun')
result = dll.add(10,1)
print('Addition value:',result)
```

Output:

```
Addition value: 11
```

Comment: Thank you thank you so much you're the best 
It's working

Answer (score -1):

I think you should check Python's `LoadLibrary` is calling "fun.dll"'s `main()` function correctly. It should look for the `DllMain()` function when loading, then you need to get the function address to call the function.

Comment: Can you give me an example please!